# Zend Layout issue

Tags: zend-framework, layout

I have a main layout, and i call my login form in this layout.
This login form stay in the header of the page, because this i can't put this in the view.

If the user wrong your email or password, will be redirect to attempt page.
In this page, i need **remove this login form in the header, and call the login form in the view.**

But i am not interested in create another layout for do this, someone know how i can do this?

My main page:

[image]

Attempt page:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zend view placeholder helper

In your layout.phtml

```
<?php if(!$this->placeholder('hide_login_form')) :?>
<?php echo new My_Login_Form(); ?>
<?endif:?>
```

Now Inside your login Action where you want to render full page form do

```
public function loginAction()
{
 $this->view->placeholder('hide_login_form')->set(true);
}
```

Comment: I can't call placeholder in the controller, and the method set don't work in the view. You have another solution for disable the placeholder in the view?